# Query to get an array item where equals to email react js firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem when i tried to get a query with filter data for a specific user logged in.
I need to get the items collection for user logged, but the query list all orders

```
const auth = getAuth(app);

const user = auth.currentUser.email;

const {buyer} = useParams();

useEffect( () =>{
    const ordersRef = collection(db, "orders")
    const q = buyer ? query(ordersRef, where("buyer", "array-contains", user.toString())): ordersRef
    getDocs(q)
        .then((resp) => {
            const newOrders = resp.docs.map((doc) => {
                return {
                    id: doc.id,
                    ...doc.data(q)

                }
            })
            setItems(newOrders)
            console.log(newOrders)
        })
},[user, buyer])
```

[image: firebase-database]

Anyone can help me?

Comment: can you share your code in the question?

Comment: hi! the code is in the 2nd image. Can you see it? O do you prefer in code format?

Comment: Code format is good, it is more easier to understand

Comment: Ok thanks, the post has been edited

Comment: You have `user.toString()` for the query parameter, but I suspect that should be `buyer`.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Explanation You can query object directly using buyer.email, array-contains help you if the buyer was an array of object.

Can you try the below code

```
const auth = getAuth(app);

const user = auth.currentUser.email;

const {buyer} = useParams();

useEffect( () =>{
    const ordersRef = collection(db, "orders")
    const q = buyer ? query(ordersRef, where("buyer.email", "==", user.toString())): ordersRef
    getDocs(q)
        .then((resp) => {
            const newOrders = resp.docs.map((doc) => {
                return {
                    id: doc.id,
                    ...doc.data(q)

                }
            })
            setItems(newOrders)
            console.log(newOrders)
        })
},[user, buyer])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried your solution but get the same answer. The query list all orders

Comment: can you try the code without ternary operator? Like below 
const q = query(ordersRef, where("buyer.email", "==", user.toString()));

not sure if it will help

Answer (score 0):

```
const auth = getAuth(app);

const user = auth.currentUser.email;

const {buyer} = useParams();

useEffect( () =>{
    const ordersRef = collection(db, "orders")
    const q = buyer ? query(ordersRef, where(buyer.email, "array-contains", buyer)): ordersRef
    getDocs(q)
        .then((resp) => {
            const newOrders = resp.docs.map((doc) => {
                return {
                    id: doc.id,
                    ...doc.data(q)

                }
            })
            setItems(newOrders)
            console.log(newOrders)
        })
},[user, buyer])
```

I tried with this update but i get the same result. The console show me all orders, not a specific orders from user. Maybe the problem is in the query?

Comment: @bhavesh-daswani do you have any idea? Appreciate your help